# Add index to new list if value of input list is numeric

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

My input list is a list of different datatypes - if the datatype is numeric (either float or int) I want to append it's index in the input list to my new list of indices.
I tried the following function, it works for the first occurrence of an int/float but then it returns the index of the first float for every following float and the index of the first integer for every following integer.

````
types_list = [str, int, float, datetime.datetime, int, int]    
numeric_indices = [] 
for i in types_list: #now here I check, whether the type of the column is numeric
    if i== int or i==float: #if it is indeed of type integer or float which means it would be numeric
        print(types_list.index(i))
        numeric_indices.append(myindex)
```
````

Comment: Are you really interested in iterating over a list of types? It would seem to make more sense to iterate over a list of data and check types as you go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) method to iterate through the elements of the `types_list` alongside each element's index:

```
types_list = [str, int, float, datetime.datetime, int, int]    
numeric_indices = [] 
for index, i in enumerate(types_list):
    if i == int or i == float:
        print(index)
        numeric_indices.append(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
def numeric(item):
    return (item == int) or (item == float)
numeric_indices = [index for index, item in enumerate(types_list) if numeric(item)]
```

would be pretty idiomatic python for what you're talking about

However, I'm assuming that the list of datatypes is derived from some actual data, which is what you're actually interested in. Something like

```
def numeric(item):
    return (isinstance(item, int)) or (isinstance(item,  float))
numeric_indices = [index for index, item in enumerate(types_list) if numeric(item)]
```

would take a list like `["a", 1, 1.2, datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 12, 15, 59, 35, 351557)]` and produce `[1,2]`, which I think is what you're really after

EDIT: another answer suggested using `str.isnumeric`, which suggests the following approach:

```
def numeric(item):
    return str(item).isnumeric()

numeric_indices = [index for index, item in enumerate(types_list) if numeric(item)]
```

which is cute